# How to call "find -exec" from nodejs spawn

Tags: node.js, find, spawn

I have a legacy perl application release script, which I'm trying to re-write in nodejs.

Part of the release process involves setting the correct attributes on all of the files in a sub-folder.

In the perl release script, this is done using back-ticks, like so...

```
my $command = `find '$code_folder' -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`;
```

This works fine.

I'm having problems though translating this to work in node.

I'm attempting to use the "spawn" npm module, like so...

```
const chalk = require("chalk"),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

let childProcess = spawn('find',['test_folder','-type','f','-exec chmod 644 {} +'],{});

childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(chalk.green(data.toString()));
});

childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(chalk.red(data.toString()));
});

childProcess.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code === 0) {
        console.log(chalk.blue(`exit_code = ${code}`));
    }
    else {
        console.log(chalk.yellow(`exit_code = ${code}`));
    }
});

childProcess.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(chalk.red(error.toString()));
});
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error...

> find: unknown predicate `-exec chmod 644 {} +'

If I leave out the -exec part, the command runs and displays all the files, as expected.

I've tried everything I can think of to escape it differently, but cannot find a way to get it to accept the "-exec" parameter.

Also, I should mention, I've also tried the following...

```
let childProcess = spawn('find',['test_folder','-type','f','-exec','chmod 644 {} +'],{});
```

It gives the error...

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

update:
I've found a way to do it. It seems a bit hacky though. If someone knows a proper way, please let me know.

The following works...

```
let childProcess = spawn('sh',['-c', 'find test_folder -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +'],{});
```

So instead of spawning a 'find' process, it spawns 'sh -c', and passes the 'find' command as an argument to that.

Comment: "cannot find a way to get it to accept the "-exec" parameter." – Hint: you found a away to get it to accept the `-type` parameter, why don't you try the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `spawn` method, then you have to pass each argument as a separate array element, like so:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const childProcess = spawn(
   'find',
   ['test_folder', '-type', 'f', '-exec', 'chmod', '644', '{}', '+'],
   {}
);
```

But I would suggest using the `exec` method. For your use case they should be identical, but `exec` has nicer interface. It accepts whole command as a string and returns buffered response, so you don't need to manage streams manually. Here is an example:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('find test_folder -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
   console.log(error, stdout, stderr);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Just what I was looking for. I'm not sure why I hadn't tried separating all the parameters like this. It works fine. The recommendation about exec is very helpful as well. It looks like it will make my code a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the permissions using the [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_chmodsync_path_mode) once you've found all your files.  I'm using Node 10 so you might need to change your syntax a little if you are using anything earlier.

```
const { chmodSync } = require('fs')
const {execFileSync} = require('child_process')

execFileSync('find',['test_folder', '-type', 'f'])
 .toString() // change from buffer to string
 .trim() //remove the new line at end of the file
 .split('\n') // each file found as array element
 .forEach(path => chmodSync(path, '644')) // Set chmod to 644
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and useful for future reference. In my case though I think I'll need to handle it all with the native find command. I could potentially have thousands of files to change, so it needs to be as fast as possible.